# Bind CSS3 Animation Callback using Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, css, knockout.js, css-animations

I'm building a "WebApp" for iPad using Knockout.js and CSS3 Animations.

The transition between different pages is animated. I want to get a JavaScript callback when the Animation ends.

Now i know you can catch the callback using Javascript like this:

```
element.addEventListener(webkitAnimationEnd, function(){callfunction()},false);
```

But isn't there a better way to do this? The "knockout way"? I want to bind the callback function using the `data-bind` attribute in the DOM rather than accessing the DOM element in my javascript code!

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** Maybe i should add that i'm new to Knockout.js and i don't know if what i'm trying to do or rather, how i'm trying to do it makes sense or if you just do it the conventional way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience there is no 'knockout way' to handle those sorts of events.

Knockout's author suggests using the KO **event** binding for simple bindings. But for more complex and/or unobtrusive event binding scenarios suggests using jQuery: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html

I'm working on a project now using Knockout and I followed his suggestion. Using some KO **event** bindings (for form submits) and some jQuery event bindings (for a window resize event in my case).

Of course, you don't need to use jQuery, but going outside the KO library in your case is probably the correct route. Have fun!

Answer (score 4):

I use [jQuery Transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) and a knockout custom binding to accomplish a sliding page transition. Basically, it slides the active page (div) out and slides a new one in. It looks good on mobile devices too (iPad, iPhone, iPod Touch, Android phones, etc.). Here is the binding:

**Javascript:**

```
    var previousElement = null;
    ko.bindingHandlers.slideVisible = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor)
        {
            var value = valueAccessor();
            $(element).toggle(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value));
        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor)
        {

            var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
            if (value)
            {
                if (previousElement == null)
                { // initial fade
                    $(element).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    //uses CSS3 Transform for smooth mobile performance
                    $(previousElement).transition({ x: '-100%' }, function () { $(this).hide(); });
                    $(element).css({ x: '100%' });
                    $(element).show().transition({ x: '0%' }, function () 
{ 
//Callback | transition finished code here
});
                }
                previousElement = element;
            }
        }
    };
```

**View Model Snippet:**

```
isPageVisible: ko.observable(false)
```

**HTML:**

```
<div data-bind="slideVisible: isPageVisible">
<!-- Page Content Here -->
</div>
```

[**JS Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/TWxy7/)